# Http POST request url contains '['

Tags: http, post, get

I am working with SharePoint using http post request.
My url contains '[' so I am getting some exception.

Does anybody knows how to send a Post or Get request if the url contains '[' or ']' character?

Answer (score 5):

Encode the brackets in the url so that `[` becomes `%5B` and `]` becomes `%5D`.
[HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

If you are generating the URL from (.NET) code, use [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx).

```
string encodedUrl = "http://example.com/awesome.aspx?title="
                  + HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode("Super & Delicious Program [v1]");

// "http://example.com/awesome.aspx?title=Super+%26+Delicious+Program+%5Bv1%5D"
```

The (roughly) equivalent method in JavaScript would be [escape()](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Encode the square brackets

```
[ == %5B
] == %5D
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, try out [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).  To decode use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: I think Sharepoint rules out the use of PHP. In any case, for URLs, you would use urlencode / rawurlencode.

Comment: I suppose he could be using PHP to do posts against a sharepoint server... but he doesn't say he his, so it seems unlikely. Rawurlencode is generally the best route to go.